# I want an AJAX file uploader like Gmail file upload with the progress bar in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'd like an AJAX file uploader like the one shown in Gmail when you're uploading a file (with the progress bar) written in PHP.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You CAN'T do this with PHP alone... You will need some JavaScript (AJAX) too. Also please consider to accept some answers on your other questions too.

Comment: yes i want javascript , jquery or any flash plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this plugins :

http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

or

http://valums.com/files/2010/file-uploader/demo.htm

or

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: Added 2 Other variant of jquery file uploader, see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

- [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/photoqueue/)
- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
- [AJAX Upload by Andrew Valums](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

Many other can be found on Google and on [this page](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/10-best-ajax-file-uploader-for-your-web-application/)

Comment: +1 for links with names and the '10 best' article (that shows examples).

Answer (score 1):

I tried [AJAX Upload by Andrew Valums](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) to upload multiple files. This works really great and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically update a JQuery [Progress Bar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar) plugin, and achieve the same look and feel.

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 1 });
  });
</script>
```

Then all you need to do is reference that progress bar and set it's value based on your actual progress:

```
$( ".selector" ).progressbar( "option", "value", <YOURVALUE>);
```

Comment: thanks , but i want source code or any tutorial i m beginners in php.