# How to upload file using ajax and insert the file into mysql database in server side using php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

in the client side I have the below code:

```
<script>
function UploadPic(p_id,status_tag,form_tag,image_tag) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(status_tag).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","file.php",true);
    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("from_tag"));
    formData.append("p_id", p_id);
    formData.append("image_tag", image_tag);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
    }
}
</script>

<form name="form_image1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr><td>Image 1: </td>
<td >
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<input name="image_1" type="file" id="image_1"> </td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="UploadPic(document.getElementsByName('product_id')[0].value,'image1_status','form_image1','image_1')">Upload Photo</button></td>
<td>
<div id="image1_status"></div></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

On server side:

```
if(!empty($p_id)&& !empty($image_tag))
{
    $imageName = $_FILES[$image_tag]['name'];
    $tmpImageName  = $_FILES[$image_tag]['tmp_name'];
    $imageSize = $_FILES[$image_tag]['size'];
    $imageType = $_FILES[$image_tag]['type'];
    $fp      = fopen($tmpImageName , 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpImageName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    echo $content;
    fclose($fp);

    $query = "insert into image_table (p_id,$image_tag) values ($p_id,$content)";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, $image_tag upload failed'); 
    echo "$image_tag uploaded successfully!";
}
else
{
    echo "error in uploading file";
}
```

my problem is that the file is not uploaded, all variables related to the file uploading are empty.

I used the same server side code to upload files using normal post request and it is working fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want an AJAX file uploader like Gmail file upload with the progress bar in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889435/i-want-an-ajax-file-uploader-like-gmail-file-upload-with-the-progress-bar-in-php)

Comment: you must use formData()

Comment: @minspace am i not using it?!. please show me.

Comment: @ATM You are using it, but the filename should be the third parameter in the append function. Please take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append