# jquery ajax multiple file upload check progress for every file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how to show progress for every images being uploaded just like in facebook uploads,

they have one `<input multiple/>` but after you selected multiple files, you can see progress bar for each images, and you can also cancel the uploading?..

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have tried some ajax xhr to show progress and can only get total of all selected files. your help is much appreciated thanks in advance.

```js
$("body").on('change', '#upload-nw-prod', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#upload-multiple-new-products').submit();
});

$('body').on('submit', '#upload-multiple-new-products', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

   $.ajax({
    url: '/nw-product-upload-mod',
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },
    success: function (data) {
                $("#nw-prod-upl-mdl").html(data);
            },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
```

```html
<form id="upload-multiple-new-products" class="pull-right" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="upload-nw-prod" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Upload products</label>
     <input id="upload-nw-prod"  multiple="" name="photo[]" type="file" accept="image/*">
     <input name="submit" value="" style="display: none;" type="submit">
</form>
```

```
//after submit (image intervention)
$photos = $request->file('photo');
$thumb_th_lgArrs    = [];
foreach ($photos as $key => $photo) {
    $img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath());
    $img->resize(300, 300, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
        $constraint->upsize();
    });
    $img->encode('jpg');
    $img->save($saveDirectory.'/'.$thumb_th_lgArrs[$key]['image_name']);
    $img->reset();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want an AJAX file uploader like Gmail file upload with the progress bar in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889435/i-want-an-ajax-file-uploader-like-gmail-file-upload-with-the-progress-bar-in-php)

Comment: thanks for the replay sir. I want to build from scratch, may you tell me what are the process being done in those plugins thank you.

Comment: show your code here

Comment: try dropzonejs plugin

Comment: ok many thanks the simplest way, I think I'll just adapt those plugins

Answer (score 0):

After playing with dropzonejs, I didnt know the process is quite that simple

1. get all images that was uploaded in the `<input multiple/>`
2. convert the images to base64
3. upload the images individualy using ajax
4. preview the progress of each image being uploaded

but I would also recommend dropdownjs very easy to implement